# Detect if an electromagnet it touching metal (without a switch)

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, electromagnetism

I have a simple 12V DC holding electromagnet connected to a microcontroller using a MOSFET - the once you buy on aliexpress or eBay for cheap [1].

How can I detect if the magnet is in full contact with a ferromagnetic disk or strike plate when I turn it on? Unfortunately I can't rely on a limit switch since the placement of the magnet & metal has too much freedom.

Is there something with the inductance of the magnet that I can sense or perhaps differences in current consumption? One other possibility is to probe using PWM.

[1] https://www.aliexpress.com/item/CL-P-20-15-Holding-Electric-Magnet-Lifting-2-5KG-25N-Solenoid-Sucker-Electromagnet-DC-6V/32761771780.html

Comment: Does the electromagnet need to be **touching** or just really close? Exactly what kind of metal would the electromagnet be touching? What sort of signal is used to drive the electromagnet? Is it dc or ac, if ac what frequency? Please provide a link to the datasheet for the electromagnet.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I've added some extra information regarding the kind of magnet. I don't have a datasheet unfortunately. It's just one of those simple magnets you get with free shipping. Full contact would be the case.

Comment: If you use an ac drive you **might** be able to see a change in current as the electromagnet approaches the metal plate, because the inductance will change. However, the magnitude of the change might be small and difficult to detect easily. Why don't you do some experiments?

Comment: I'll do some research on an ac drive. I plan to do some experiments in a day or two and hope to get some suggestions & ideas here to test then.

Answer (score 2):

Those electromagnets have both poles physically on the same side, so the magnetic circuit should see a large change in reluctance when it comes in contact with a ferromagnetic material (as opposed to the field being closed in air). You should be able to see that contact as a relatively large change in inductance.

You would need to use an AC signal of a high-enough frequency to be able to apply it alongside your DC drive, or you can modify your DC drive to apply an AC component (e.g., PWM-style pulses).

Be aware that the body of the electromagnet is conductive, which means that it will present high losses to any AC excitation.